# How to dynamically update dictonary (key/data) in python

Tags: python, loops, dynamic, xlrd

This is a test file where I am trying out the excel read package, so that is why the variables are named lazily.I am trying to read data from an excel file and have it convert to JSON, but I am having trouble iterating through the data and have it put into dictionary.

```
import xlrd
from collections import OrderedDict
import json


# Open the workbook and select the first worksheet
wb = xlrd.open_workbook('Test_Book.xlsx')
sh = wb.sheet_by_index(0)



data_list = []


data = OrderedDict()

for i in range(1, sh.nrows):

    for j in range(1, sh.ncols+1):
        data[sh.row_values(0)[i-1]] = sh.row_values(i)[j-1]

        #data[j] = ({sh.row_values(0)[j-(sh.nrows - sh.ncols)] : sh.row_values(j)})

        #print("I = "+i.__str__())
        #print("J = "+j.__str__())
    data_list.append(data)

# Serialize the list of dicts to JSON
j = json.dumps(data_list)



with open('data.json', 'w') as f:
    f.write(j)
```

I have tried a nested for loop, but the data is not in the correct order.
The keys seems to work fine, but when I try to the same thing with the data it does not work.
(This one I had to manually add the data one row after another, the second part is where I tried to dynamically add the data)
Here's how it needs to look like.

```
OrderedDict([('ID', 2.0), ('Make', 'Toyota'), ('Model', 'Corolla'), ('Milage', 15956.0)])
OrderedDict([('ID', 3.0), ('Make', 'Jeep'), ('Model', 'Compass'), ('Milage', 114885.0)])
OrderedDict([('ID', 4.0), ('Make', 'Honda'), ('Model', 'Pilot'), ('Milage', 3830.0)])
```

Here's how it looks like with my code execution

```
OrderedDict([('ID', 5.0), ('Make', 'Subaru'), ('Model', 'Outback'), ('Milage', 20424.0), ('Condition', 'Fair')])
OrderedDict([('ID', 5.0), ('Make', 'Subaru'), ('Model', 'Outback'), ('Milage', 20424.0), ('Condition', 'Fair')])
OrderedDict([('ID', 5.0), ('Make', 'Subaru'), ('Model', 'Outback'), ('Milage', 20424.0), ('Condition', 'Fair')])
```

Comment: `data` is a reference, so at the end you have one list with 3 references to the same `OrderedDict`. You need to reset `data` after the first `for` statement doing `data = OrderedDict ()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only initializing `data` `OrderedDict` once outside all the loops, and inside it seems like you keep changing the values for the same keys again and again , this would keep changing the same `OrderedDict` object, and at end you are append the same OrderedDict object into `data_list`.

You would need to create a new `data` OrderedDict for each iteration (of outer loop).

Try something like -

```
for i in range(1, sh.nrows):
    data = OrderedDict()
    for j in range(1, sh.ncols+1):
        data[sh.row_values(0)[j-1]] = sh.row_values(i)[j-1]
        data3.append(sh.row_values(i)[j-1])

        #data[j] = ({sh.row_values(0)[j-(sh.nrows - sh.ncols)] : sh.row_values(j)})
        #print("I = "+i.__str__())
        #print("J = "+j.__str__())
    data_list.append(data)
```

Also, you do not seem to be doing anything with `data3` , why is it there? If you do not need it, remove it.

Comment: `OrderedDict([('ID', 'New')])
OrderedDict([('Make', 'New')])
OrderedDict([('Model', 'Poor')])
OrderedDict([('Milage', 'Good')])
OrderedDict([('Condition', 'Fair')])
`

Comment: that is the output that I am getting. And sorry i was using data 3 to see if i could append it to the dictionary data separately

Comment: Made a small change - `data[sh.row_values(0)[j-1]] = sh.row_values(i)[j-1]` , check now

Comment: Glad I could be of help :)

Answer (score 1):

In python, most of the variable are references, so you have to be careful when storing them:

```
>>> list_of_lists = []
>>> l = [1, 2, 3]           # Creating a random list
>>> list_of_lists.append(l) # Storing it
>>> l[1] = 'Blob'           # Updating it! Here's the problem.
>>> list_of_lists.append(l) # Storing it again
>>> l = ['New', 'List']     # Creating a new list
>>> list_of_lists.append(l) # Storing it
>>> list_of_lists           # Notice that the 2 first list are equals
[[1, 'Blob', 3], [1, 'Blob', 3], ['New', 'List']]
>>> list_of_lists[0] is list_of_lists[1]
True
```

---

In your case, you have only **one** `data` object, and you store 3 references to it in `data_list`. You have to « reset » your `data` variable at each loop by reinitialising to an empty `OrderedDict` to get the expected result:

```
for i in range(1, sh.nrows):
    data = OrderedDict () # here
    for j in range(1, sh.ncols+1):
        data[sh.row_values(0)[j-1]] = sh.row_values(i)[j-1]
        data3.append(sh.row_values(i)[j-1])
    data_list.append(data)
```

---

Another way (less pythonic, IMO), is to explicitly create a copy of your `data` variable before storing it into your `data_list`:

```
for i in range(1, sh.nrows):
    for j in range(1, sh.ncols+1):
        data[sh.row_values(0)[j-1]] = sh.row_values(i)[j-1]
        data3.append(sh.row_values(i)[j-1])
    data_list.append(data.copy ())
```

Comment: `OrderedDict([('ID', 'New')]) OrderedDict([('Make', 'New')]) OrderedDict([('Model', 'Poor')]) OrderedDict([('Milage', 'Good')]) OrderedDict([('Condition', 'Fair')]) ` That is the output I am getting when I  as you said initialize it.

Comment: I was wondering if there is a way to have one instance and loop through it while dynamically adding data to it. It is the assignment of data to the key that is not working.

Comment: @user3570849 You had a little mistake (`i-1` instead of `j-1` in your assignment). If it still does not work, please show us what your datasheet looks like.